# PHP $_GET values doesn't work when using rewrite rules

Tags: php

In profile user $_GET doesn't work fine. 
I'm using URL Rewriting

its

```
RewriteBase /pline/
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1
```

- if user url is (website.com/username?photos) not working
- if user url    is (website.com/profile.php?photos) working

  ```
  if(isset($_GET['friends'])){
      echo 'Friends area!';
  }
  else{
      if(isset($_GET['photos'])){
          echo 'Photos area!';
      }
      else{
          echo 'Profile area!';
      }
  }
  ```

How can I solve this problem?

thank you

Comment: website.com/username?photos is missing .php i.e. username.php. Or you should use URL Rewriting for clean URLs

Comment: I'm using URL Rewriting but when I use $_get its doesn't work fine

Comment: use [L,QSA] on rewrite rule

Comment: What are your "username" and "profile" pages - are they supposed to be separate?

Comment: What are your rewrite rules. problem occurs there. not in your php codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your rewrite rules, there is only a one variable called `username`

so in your php, only `$_GET['username']` will get values

That is default variable is username. so you should use this kind of links: `website.com/value_for_username`

if you want more variables, use `website.com/value_for_username&var1=value1&var2=value2` and so on.
and also update rewrite rules to match it if necessary.

Comment: thank you for answer. but this doesn't work fine too. I get a server error

Comment: its [Error 500] I think something wrong in the code

Comment: Thank you for helping @Janaka I solved the problem          `RewriteBase /pline/ 
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1&var=$1 [L,QSA] 
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1&var=$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

$_GET['photos'] are definend in both cases!

All the time this code go to echo "Photos area"

Note, that in you exemple you username url no have PHP extension!

You can try with value in $_GET parameter, try some like website.com/username.php?section=photos

```
swich($_GET['section']){
   case 'product':
     echo "Product section";
   break;
  ....
}
```